# Is it possible to create and store 2 person Avatar Kinect sessions offline?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect, kinect-fun-labs

I am trying to understand the requirements and capabilities of Avatar Kinect for local (offline) use. This involves a number of steps:

- Is it possible to play with two players locally? (e.g. two people sitting in front of the same console + sensor)
- Is it still possible if only one player has an Xbox Live account, and it's a free account? (If not, will it work if both players have a free Xbox Live account.)
- Can a video + audio recording of the session be made?
- Can the recording be stored locally (and not uploaded anywhere)?

If the answer is simply "Yes", can the recording be copied off the console, and if so in what format?

Answer (score 1):

The features list of Avatar Kinect indicates that it's possible for two people to play offline (see http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Avatar-Kinect/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8025848081a under the second page of the game overview).

Once you have downloaded it, use the Guide menu to access and open it [as described in this answer for opening Kinect Fun Labs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97832/5138). (Press Guide button, scroll to "Games and Apps", select "Recent", press <kbd>RB</kbd> twice to open "All" tab, select Avatar Kinect from the list.)

To share photos and videos from your Xbox Kinect, you upload it to Kinect Share https://kinectshare.com/ where you will have the option to download it or share it via facebook, youtube and other social networks.  This service works with the free silver live account.